# Closed forms of $\int_A^B \sin(\sin(ax))dx$ and $\int_A^B \sin(\sin(ax)) \cdot \sin(\sin(bx))dx$

Tags: bessel-functions, differential-algebra, integrable-systems

I would like to know if:

1. $\int_A^B \sin(\sin(ax))dx$ has a closed-form? The solution of Maple requires the presence of Struve functions in its expression. But at least Maple is able to solve it, so even if complicated I guess it has an analytical form.
2. $\int_A^B \sin(\sin(ax)) \cdot \sin(\sin(bx))dx$ has a closed-form? this one Maple was not able to solve. I tried to find a similar expression in this [tables of Bessel functions](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiOmLqc59XSAhVHNxQKHfofB3oQFggcMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.eah-jena.de%2F~rsh%2FForschung%2FStoer%2Fbesint.pdf&usg=AFQjCNHY-b9gkQTU7sIDurpyBEtCsGu8Fw&sig2=-4rHLlhhJOY5QSw3TcLxFg) but there are none looking like these one. And with Liouville's theorem and the [Risch algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risch_algorithm) I am a bit lost in the differential algebra to prove that it is not integrable.

Comment: Is Maple able to provide the nswer for any $A,B$ ?

Comment: No. Only if A, B are proportional to Pi

Comment: For examples, for integer $k$: The first integral with $a=2k+1,A=0,B=\pi$ comes out to $\frac{\pi}{a}\mathbf{H}_0(1)$. With $a=4k+1\text{ or }4k+3,A=0,B=\pi/2$, we have $\frac{\pi}{2a}\mathbf{H}_0(1)$, and with $a=4k+2,A=0,B=\pi/2$ we have $\frac{\pi}{a}\mathbf{H}_0(1)$. In all cases, $\mathbf{H}_0$ is one of the [Struve functions](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/StruveFunction.html).

Comment: @MarkS. yes, but then it means there is not analytical expression for the closed form, because depending on the chosen Maple&Mathematica will return something depending on the Bessel and/or Struve functions or will not be able to find the integral. How to express this nicely? And if possible proving that is has no closed form (using Liouville's theorem, or Risch's algorithm, or something similar)

Answer (score 0):

For $\int_A^B\sin\sin ax~dx$ ,

$\int_A^B\sin\sin ax~dx$

$=\int_A^B\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^n\sin^{2n+1}ax}{(2n+1)!}~dx$

$=-\int_A^B\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^n\sin^{2n}ax}{a(2n+1)!}~d(\cos ax)$

$=\int_A^B\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^{n+1}(1-\cos^2ax)^n}{a(2n+1)!}~d(\cos ax)$

$=\int_A^B\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\dfrac{(-1)^{n+1}C_k^n(-1)^k\cos^{2k}ax}{a(2n+1)!}~d(\cos ax)$

$=\int_A^B\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\dfrac{(-1)^{n+k+1}n!\cos^{2k}ax}{a(2n+1)!k!(n-k)!}~d(\cos ax)$

$=\left[\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\dfrac{(-1)^{n+k+1}n!\cos^{2k+1}ax}{a(2n+1)!k!(n-k)!(2k+1)}\right]_A^B$

$=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\dfrac{(-1)^{n+k+1}n!(\cos^{2k+1}aB-\cos^{2k+1}aA)}{a(2n+1)!k!(n-k)!(2k+1)}$

For $\int_A^B\sin\sin ax\sin\sin bx~dx$ ,

$\int_A^B\sin\sin ax\sin\sin bx~dx$

$=\dfrac{1}{2}\int_A^B\cos(\sin ax-\sin bx)~dx-\dfrac{1}{2}\int_A^B\cos(\sin ax+\sin bx)~dx$

$=\dfrac{1}{2}\int_A^B\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^n(\sin ax-\sin bx)^{2n}}{(2n)!}~dx-\dfrac{1}{2}\int_A^B\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^n(\sin ax+\sin bx)^{2n}}{(2n)!}~dx$